# ModuleNotFoundError when running Docker-Image

Tags: python, docker, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I am currently trying to build and run a Docker-Image around a software of mine. The building completes successfully, when I want to run the Image however the statement

```
File "tts_api_graves/app.py", line 6, in <module>
File "/container/tts_api_graves/synthesize_custom.py", line 8, in <module>
from tts_api_graves.utils.synthesis import synthesis
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tts_api_graves'
```

appears. The folder structure is as follows:

```
Dockerfile 
tts_api_graves/
              app.py        
              synthesize_custom.py
                            utils/        
                                 synthesize.py
```

I am aware of the fact that the import-command could just be put as `from utils.synthesis import synthesis`, since the `utils`-folder is in the same directory as `synthesize_custom` (where the import-command is at). There however are many more imports from the `tts_api_graves`-folder in files located in sub-folders, which is why decided to add the *parent-folder* of `tts_api_graves` to my python-paths within the container. Consequently the above mentioned import should work. My Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.0.1-cuda10.0-cudnn7-runtime 


WORKDIR /container

RUN export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH: /container"

ADD . .

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libsndfile1 espeak && \
    apt-get clean && \
     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

COPY requirements.txt /container

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV LANG C.UTF-8

CMD python tts_api_graves/app.py
```

You can see that in the 3rd line of the `Dockerfile` I added the according python-path. I even checked its existence via `sys.path` and it was successfully appended. The structure within the container now is:

```
container/
         Dockerfile
         tts_api_graves/
                       app.py
                       synthesize_custom.py
                                     utils/
                                          synthesis.py
```

and `/container` is appended to my system-paths and still the imports `from tts_api_graves.xy` don't work. What have I done wrong? Please don't be too harsh on me, I am pretty new to Docker. Thx in advance.